# How does table state in postgresql transaction works?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If i call some procedure that do a batch job, that takes 10 mins, for example.
Which is in turn accessing some table. And what happens if that table  which accessed within running procedure (transaction) is updated within these 10 minutes? Transaction will ignore these changes and keep state of the table at moment of a procedure call? Example:
**users** table

```
|user_id|some_value|
|-------|----------|
|      1|       213|
|      3|       444|

-- and so on
```

If **some_value** for **user_id** = 3 is changed to **1** but transaction is still running, processing users table row by row, and user with id = 1 is not processed at the moment of **some_value** update, what value is going to be in procedure (transaction)? **1** or **444**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a transaction always sees its own writings: if you run `update mytable set some_value=1 where user_id=3` as long as this transaction is running, `select some_value from mytable where user_id=3` returns 1 in this transaction. But other concurrent transactions cannot see this "pending" update.

If this transaction is ended by ROLLBACK no one will be able to see this value: not a new transaction in the same session or another transaction in another session.

If this transaction is ended by COMMIT, all other transactions will see this new value whether they run in another session or in the same session.

This assumes that the default transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED.

Comment: Sorry, still dont get it. I dont update value inside batch job, i only read (row by row) e.g. SELECT some_value FROM users WHERE user_id = 3; I mean what value is going to be after this select if other concurrent update was happened on same user right before select.

Comment: I rephrase: as long as the transaction running the concurrent update is not completed by COMMIT the batch job *cannot* see the concurrent update. After transaction end by COMMIT of the concurrent update everyone can see the UPDATE including the batch job.